# Revert back to last zoom-in on google maps

Tags: android, google-maps, markerclusterer

Is the a way that I can reverse my last click/change/zoom-in/action on google maps v2 in android when I click FloatingActionButton. For my app, I have 3-4 different cluster buckets on map, when I click on a bucket -> map zoom-in all markers in that bucket. And I want to implement a floating button, map go back to previous state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you use this initially:

```
mMap.animateCamera( CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo( 17.0f ) );
```

This will change the zoom value to any desired value between minimum value=2.0 and maximum value=21.0. Then again click on the fab call this function again.

If you want to use lats and longs you can also try this:

```
LatLng marks = new LatLng(some_lats, some_longs);
mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(marks, 17.0f));
```

Comment: Humm... got it let me try then. Currently I am using LatLngBounds to bound all the markers on the map. This seem not to be a good one. anyway I will try it out.